# C# Winform Reset Everything to its starting point

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I want to bring my whole winform project to it's initial state when I press a certain `Button`. All the `Button`s, `TextBox`es, `ComboBox`es go back to their starting point as well as all the font and background colors. I've tried the foreach(`Button`s) and stuff but it's not working at all so... Any idea if it's possible or how to do so?

Comment: Of course it's possible.  You need to show your relevant code.

Comment: what do you mean starting point, at the end of whatever action you have performed you could do this `textbox1.Text = " ";` even `comboBox1.Text = " ";`

Comment: Easy, restart the program

Comment: please post the code where you try to "foreach(buttons) and stuff"

Comment: @Mong  Zhu, code not needed - if  Zellarius tried to remove controls from form controls inside foreach loop, is clear why it does not work without sources :-)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean single form, started at application start by method

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

or some similar.
Replace this code in Main() function  with

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
f.Show(); 
Application.Run();
```

Now you application will run until Exit() or ExitThread(), look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900(v=vs.110).aspx

Now you can use code to restart your Form1, the application will continue running after your Form1 closed

```
this.Close();
Form1 f = new Form1();
f.Show();
```

My solution is more detail explanation of  MickyD's comment :-)